# Printing with indentation in C

Tags: c, algorithm, printf, indentation

Which way is the best for line up all the output on the right ?

Example: for powers of 2:

```
        2
        4
        8
       16
       32
       64
      128
      256
      512
     1024
     2048

     ...

134217728
```

If my last number has N digits, how print the first one (which in this case has just one digit) with (N - 1) spaces on left ?

Comment: Hont: Lookup the format parameter for `printf`.

Comment: You can use `*` for the field width in `printf`. Then it gets the width from a parameter.

Comment: The [documentation for the `printf` family of functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) is a far better resource to hit before this site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can supply a computed field width to `printf()` using `*`. So after you calculate the maximum number of digits, you can do:

```
printf("%*d\n", max_digits, value);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the width trick of `printf` as said here: [Printf reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)

`printf ("Width trick: %*d \n", 5, 10);`

will produce

`Width trick:    10`

Answer (score 1):

Example

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    for (int i=2; i<134217729;i=i*2)
        printf("%*d\n",20, i);
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
           2
           4
           8
          16
          32
          64
         128
         256
         512
        1024
        2048
        4096
        8192
       16384
       32768
       65536
      131072
      262144
      524288
     1048576
     2097152
     4194304
     8388608
    16777216
    33554432
    67108864
   134217728
```

Comment: What if I used char instead of numbers ?

Comment: It works exactly the same, the *flags* are the same for each *conversion specifier*.

Comment: @ViníciusGuardianoSouza You can use `strlen(char *)` to find the length of a string in C, then you format it accordingly.